# Pure declarative jenkins pipeline: variable across stages

Tags: variables, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to set a variable in one stage and use that in a following stage in a pure declarative Jenkins pipeline.

I DO NOT want to:

- Use a script block to set the variable.
- Use a temporary file to store the value.

Is it possible?

Things I have already tried:

- Usage of environment block: can't override variables set in global environment block inside a stage. Variables inside stage specific environment blocks don't outlive the scope of a specific stage.
- Exporting an environment variable (using 'sh' step) doesn't got beyond the scope of stage.
- Direct variable assignment inside "steps" doesn't seem to be possible.

Please help !

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `script` block ? It would solve your problem

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I am as of now using script block only...  however, I am trying to align towards declarative syntax as a standard, as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to solve this, is to create a temp variable via a shared library. This way, you can keep it declarative. Well, at least in the pipeline.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

There is probably an easier way, but this is the only thing I can think of, to keep it declarative.

1. create a shared lib.
2. Create for the shared lib a vars/tempVar.goovy

```
    def temp = null

    def call(args) {
        temp = args.value
    }
```

3. import it to your pipeline and use it.

```
        stages {
            stage('Stage - 1') {
                steps {
                    tempVar value: 'Test Temp Var'
                }
            }
            stage('Stage - 2') {
                steps {
                    echo "${tempVar.temp}"
                }
            }
        }
```